# Conditional statement that modifies two variables

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I have the following data frame:

```
dat<-data.frame(site=c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), 
               landuse= rep(c("urban", "dev", "undev"),2), 
               percent= c(30,30,40, 50, 30, 20))
```

For each site, I want to filter for rows where the `percent` is greater than or equal to 50, but for sites where all `landuse`  categories do not meet the minimum criteria, the `landuse` entry is changed to "mixed" and the `percent` is changed to 100.

The result data frame would look like this:

```
 result<- data.frame(site= c("A", "B"), landuse=c("mixed", "urban"), percent= c(100, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  summarise(landuse = if (all(percent < 50)) "mixed" else landuse[percent >= 50],
            percent = ifelse(landuse == 'mixed', 100, percent))

#  site  landuse percent
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 A     mixed       100
#2 B     urban        50
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(site) %>% mutate(landuse = case_when(all(percent < 50) ~ 'mixed', TRUE ~ landuse), 
                                  percent= case_when(landuse == 'mixed' ~ 100, TRUE ~ percent)) %>% 
                                  filter(percent >= 50) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   site [2]
  site  landuse percent
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 A     mixed       100
2 B     urban        50
```